# xml: create xhtml document via xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xhtml

I'm stucked with a xslt for-each-loop.

The xml source file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="party.xsl"?>
<party date="31.12.01">
<guest name="Albert">
    <drink>wine</drink>
    <drink>beer</drink>
    <status single="true" sober="false" />
</guest>
<guest name="Martina">
    <drink>apple juice</drink>
    <status single="true" sober="true" />
</guest>
<guest name="Zacharias">
    <drink>wine</drink>
    <status single="false" sober="false" />
</guest>
</party>
```

I'd like to get the following output:

- Albert drinks: wine ,  beer ,
- Martina drinks: apple juice
- Zacharias drinks: wine ,

Therefore i wrote following XSLT file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
    <head></head>
    <body bgcolor="white">
        <xsl:for-each select="party/guest">
        <ul><li><b><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></b>
            <xsl:text> drinks: </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="drink"/>
            <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
        </li></ul>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Using the XSLT file above i get following output:

- Albert drinks: wine,
- Martina drinks: apple juice,
- Zacharias drinks: wine,

How do i have to change my XSLT file, that i get all drinks form the guests displayed?
Thanks a lot for your support!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* just nest another level of `<xsl:for-each select="drink">`.

I recommend to avoid `<xsl:for-each>`, though. Also, don't cram *everything* into a single do-it-all template.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
    <head></head>
    <body bgcolor="white">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="party" />
    </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="party">
  <ul>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="guest" />
  </ul>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="guest">
  <li>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(@name, ' drinks: ')" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="drink" />
  </li>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="drink">
  <xsl:value-of select="." />
  <xsl:if test="position() &lt; last()">, </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!
Why do you recommend to avoid <xsl:for.each>?

Comment: Because XSLT is not an imperative language and "for each" is an imperative paradigm. Using it tends to produce monolithic, deeply nested code that's impossible to re-use (and therefore often contains a lot of copy/paste duplication). It's not that there is no use at all for it, but in 95% of all cases I've seen it is used inappropriately. Resist the impulse to write an `<xsl:for-each>` and concentrate on writing `<xsl:template>` and using `<xsl:apply-templates>`, like shown above. The result will almost always be better code.